# Increase performance of a HttpsURLConnection, getInputStream() very slow

Tags: java, android, performance, httpurlconnection

This is basically how I am reading the content from an URL and get the content in the variable `result`. The result is a json parsed after.

I was wondering if it was a way to increase the performance of this request as it takes up to 4~5 seconds while I would like it to take, if possible, less than 2.

Thing is `trustAllHosts()` and `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));` seems to take some time, but I'm not sure about that. Any idea will be appreciated!

```
try {
        URL url;
        // get URL content
        url = new URL(apiURL);
        trustAllHosts();
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("some values here");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);

        in=conn.getInputStream();

        // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while ((line=br.readLine())!= null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        result=builder.toString();
        //System.out.print(result);
        br.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        result=null;
    } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        result=null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        result=null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        result=null;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        try {
            conn.disconnect();
        }catch(Exception e){}

        return result;
    }
```

`trustAllHosts()` :

```
/**
     * Trust every server - dont check for any certificate
     */
    private static void trustAllHosts() {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: usually  using buffered reader on a web connection takes longer because you are talking to the server, try measuring reading from a file instead and see if the internet connection is the issue

Comment: I tried, I'm pretty sure it is as it takes a similar time when I remove everything after    in=conn.getInputStream();

Comment: That indicates that it is the request processing at the server that is taking the time, not this code.

Comment: I don't think so... The same thing with iOs works in less than 1 second. Here in=conn.getInputStream();  is reponsible of the long time it takes, and I don't know how to fix it. I tried to stop using the cache and reducing the timeout but its still slow...

Comment: @Virthuss Did you ever end up resolving this issue?

Comment: @PaulWagland Never succeeded. I finished my internship few months after and the bug was still there.